What is the exact compiler optimization applied here expect for tail recursion elimination?
I'm compiling a simple C program, implementing an inorder tree traversal function:
void inorderTraversal(struct TreeNode* root) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    inorderTraversal(root->left);  
    printf("%d ", root->val);  
    inorderTraversal(root->right);  
}

Then I compile the .c file using: gcc inorder.c -O2 -o inorder_O2
When I try to decompile the inorder_O2 file with BinaryNinja, I get the High Level IL version of this function:

void inorderTraversal(int32_t* arg1){
    int32_t* i_1 = arg1
    if (arg1 != 0)
        int32_t* i
        do
            int32_t* j_2 = *(i_1 + 8)
            int32_t* j_1 = j_2
            if (j_2 != 0)
                int32_t* j
                do
                    int32_t* k_2 = *(j_1 + 8)
                    int32_t* k_1 = k_2
                    if (k_2 != 0)
                        int32_t* k
                        do
                            int32_t* r15_1 = *(k_1 + 8)
                            if (r15_1 != 0)
                                do
                                    int32_t* rbx_1 = *(r15_1 + 8)
                                    if (rbx_1 != 0)
                                        do
                                            int32_t* r13_1 = *(rbx_1 + 8)
                                            if (r13_1 != 0)
                                                do
                                                    int32_t* r12_1 = *(r13_1 + 8)
                                                    if (r12_1 != 0)
                                                        do
                                                            int32_t* r14_1 = *(r12_1 + 8)
                                                            if (r14_1 != 0)
                                                                do
                                                                    int32_t* r9_1 = *(r14_1 + 8)
                                                                    if (r9_1 != 0)
                                                                        do
                                                                            inorderTraversal(*(r9_1 + 8))
                                                                            __printf_chk(flag: 1, format: &data_2004, zx.q(*r9_1))
                                                                            r9_1 = *(r9_1 + 0x10)
                                                                        while (r9_1 != 0)
                                                                    __printf_chk(flag: 1, format: &data_2004, zx.q(*r14_1))
                                                                    r14_1 = *(r14_1 + 0x10)
                                                                while (r14_1 != 0)
                                                            __printf_chk(flag: 1, format: &data_2004, zx.q(*r12_1))
                                                            r12_1 = *(r12_1 + 0x10)
                                                        while (r12_1 != 0)
                                                    __printf_chk(flag: 1, format: &data_2004, zx.q(*r13_1))
                                                    r13_1 = *(r13_1 + 0x10)
                                                while (r13_1 != 0)
                                            __printf_chk(flag: 1, format: &data_2004, zx.q(*rbx_1))
                                            rbx_1 = *(rbx_1 + 0x10)
                                        while (rbx_1 != 0)
                                    __printf_chk(flag: 1, format: &data_2004, zx.q(*r15_1))
                                    r15_1 = *(r15_1 + 0x10)
                                while (r15_1 != 0)
                            __printf_chk(flag: 1, format: &data_2004, zx.q(*k_1))
                            k = *(k_1 + 0x10)
                            k_1 = k
                        while (k != 0)
                    __printf_chk(flag: 1, format: &data_2004, zx.q(*j_1))
                    j = *(j_1 + 0x10)
                    j_1 = j
                while (j != 0)
            __printf_chk(flag: 1, format: &data_2004, zx.q(*i_1))
            i = *(i_1 + 0x10)
            i_1 = i
        while (i != 0)
}


I guess a tail recursioin elimination is conducted since there is only one recursion call left. What I do not know is what make the function a big bunch of nested loops? Is there an exact compiler optimization name for it?
That is, I'm mainly want to know the name or a description of the technique, rather than a compiler option to turn it on or off.

It looks like tail recursion elimination combined with loop unrolling.

If you compile with -Os it should remove the loop unrolling.

@lan Abbott If it's loop unrolling, I think there should be several calls to root->left?

Tail call optimization means that the whole inefficient recursion could be removed entirely and replaced by an inlined loop. The actual name of the optimization technique would be function inlining and compilers are generally only able to do that if the recursion is of the tail call flavour, but perhaps not even then.

Looking at the generated assembly, gcc in particular does some mighty strange optimization which I can't really explain. Both gcc and clang fail to get rid of the recursion entirely, so this code is inefficient. Both managed to get rid of the last inorderTraversal(root->right); call though. (I can tell by making a simple struct with left/right nodes and see which stack offset the assembler is going for in the recursive call.) Basically the optimized code is making sure we're at the correct node and then printing afterwards. The lesson learnt is the same as always: avoid recursion.

To interpret the decompiled code, it would help to confirm the definition of struct TreeNode. I'm guessing struct TreeNode { int data; struct TreeNode *left; struct TreeNode *right; }.

@Lundin Yes, function inlining would be a better fit for what is going on. I wonder what heuristic the compiler uses to break out of the potentially infinite inlining? Maybe when it runs out of registers?

Compiling with gcc -O2 -fno-inline eliminates the inlining.

The recursion on root->right is a tail call, so it can be eliminated. All the do-while loops are these eliminated tail calls.
The recursion on root->left is not in tail position, so it can't be eliminated like this. Instead, the compiler open-codes the first 8 levels of recursion using nested if statements.
If the tree is deeper than 8 levels, it makes an actual call back to the function. You can see that in the innermost do block.
Now that I think about this a little more, I might have it backward which optimizations are the tail calls and which are the non-tail calls.

Thank you very much! That solves most of my questions. BTW, is "open-coding" or "inline" the exact/correct terminology to describe the expanded 8 levels of root->left?

@XushuDai "Loop unroll" might be the term.

@XushuDai "inlining", "function inlining", "inline expansion", etc.

@XushuDai It's a little bit of both. open-coding and inlining are equivalent. Inlining a tail recursion effectively turns it into a loop, and then we can unroll some iterations of the loop.
